# I keep receiving an error message when I create a DOM Event in JS

Tags: dom-events

I am learning DOM Events and I keep receiving an error message.

my code is the top half works perfectly however the remove section keeps getting the following "Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementByClassName is not a function
    at js.js:7"

any advice much appreciated.

```
`var button= document.getElementById("button");

button.addEventListener('click', function() {
    alert ("Click!!!!!!!!!!");
});

var remove = document.getElementByClassName("remove");

remove.addEventListener('click', function() {
    return ("removed!!!!!!!!!!");
});`
```

Answer (score 0):

You may have a type error, remember you are referencing many dom elements and not just one
it should be getElement**s**ByClassName not getElementByClassName
 which you can then loop over the elements using array method to append listener on each. Example code below;

```js
let remove = document.getElementsByClassName("remove");
remove.forEach(elem => {
elem.addEventListener("click",myEventHandler);
});
```